# utcNow in Power Automate is using incorrect day (`dd`)

Tags: date, datetime, automation, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I'm running into a timezone issue when running my Flows on a schedule - and I can't seem to find a solution for it.

My timezone is currently `+10:00` from UTC - Sydney, Australia.

For simplicities sake, I have a reoccurrence trigger running at `06:00` (6am local time) and `12:00` (12pm local time).

When I run my Actions - anything that needs a `StartTime` and an `EndTime` - I pass in the following parameters:

| StartTime | Endtime |
| --- | --- |
| `formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"22:00:00.0000000Z')` | `formatDateTime( addDays(utcNow(), 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"08:00:00.0000000Z')` |

The `22:00:00.0000000Z` and `08:00:00.0000000Z` above translate directly to 8am and 6pm respectively - essentially the entire work day hours.

#### Issue

When the trigger runs on the first occurrence, the StartTime and the EndTime are outputted to these values:

| Tigger time - local | UTC date time | Start time UTC parameter | End time UTC parameter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-**27** 06:00 | 2022-09-**26** 20:00 | 2022-09-**26**T22:00:00.000000Z | 2022-09-**27**T08:00:00.000000Z |

When the trigger runs on the second occurrence, the StartTime and the EndTime are outputted to these values:

| Tigger time - local | UTC date time | Start time UTC parameter | End time UTC parameter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-**27** 12:00 | 2022-09-**27** 02:00 | 2022-09-**27**T22:00:00.000000Z | 2022-09-**28**T08:00:00.000000Z |

Because the UTC date time has ticked over past midnight, the date value (`dd`) is now *the next day* due to the `addDays(utcNow(), 1)` expression.

This causes issues on the scripting of the Flow as when limiting the StartTime and EndTime of other actions, depending on when the Trigger runs is either looking at the local time's "Today" events or "Tomorrow" events.

---

For example, if I schedule an Out of Office / Automatic reply - and I schedule it to run on the `06:00` trigger, it will set my Automatic Reply to today - local time - 8am to 6pm. However, when it runs at the second trigger, `12:00` it will set my Automatic Reply to tomorrow - local time - 8am to 6pm.

Though this *is not* how I am using it, you can see it affects what actions do and perform.

Is there a way to ensure that it is always working of the current local date (`dd`) regardless if the UTC time has ticked over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the other solutions seem logical in their workings, they dont account for daylight savings and other date time issues.

For the solution I ended up hard coding some of the data and calculations:

1. Action: "Convert time zone"

   1. Base time: trigger time
   2. Format string: `Universal sortable date/time pattern [u]`
   3. Source: +10:00
   4. Destination: UTC
2. Action: "Compose"

   1. Expression: `formatDateTime( body('Convert_time_zone'), 'dd')`

Then for the start time UTC:

1. Action: Initialise variable

   1. Name: Output Start Date Time
   2. Type: String
   3. Value: yyyy-MM-[Output from Compose*]"T"22:00:00.0000000Z')

   `*` in that `[Output from Compose]` I made it an expression so I could subtract 1 day, using: `sub( int(outputs('Compose')), 1)`

---

This way I could always get my local date (`dd`) then manually shift the date, and set it as well as the time for start time.

Then I would use that local date for the End date time, and manually set the time.

Not the cleanest solution, but it works 100% of the time regardless of daylight savings or any time conversions. It is however not transferrable to other users without them editing the info.

Comment: If I am not all wrong, you will have a problem with that calculation when UTC is in another month from your local time - like on every morning at 6am local time on the first of a month.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the addHours function instead of hard coding the hours in the formatdatetime function?

For the 6 am run I would try for the start time

```
formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(), 2), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.0000000Z')
```

And for the end time

```
formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(), 12), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.0000000Z')
```

You could also use a check to see which occurence run it is an combine that with the addhours approach.

```
equals(utcNow('HH'), '20')
```

Comment: But if I edit the hours won't it be affecting my use of those 8am-6pm time blocks? So if it ran at midday, it wouldn't report back 8am-6pm, but it would be adding 2 or 12 hours

Comment: My idea was that based on which time it is running we just calculate/add the hours for the next 08am moment. Btw, I made some calculation mistakes earlier. It should have been 20 for HH, that is 6 am, correct? And for the start time we want to add either 2 for the 6 am run and 20 for the 12pm run.
`if(equals(utcNow('HH'), '20'), formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(), 2), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.0000000Z'), formatDateTime(addHours(utcNow(), 20), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.0000000Z')`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you want to do your Start time and End time calculations based on your LOCAL date, but you are doing the calculation based on the UTC date and thus get the wrong day, if UTC ticked over.

I guess the solution would be, to do your Start and End time calculations based on the LOCAL time instead of utcNow() and then transform the resulting LOCAL Start and End times into UTC times to be used as Start Time and End Time parameters.

Something to the effect of:

```
convertFromUtc(utcNow(),'+10:00','yyyy-MM-dd"T"06:00:00.000000')
```

to get the local start time of the current day and then from there

```
convertToUtc(localStartTime,'+10:00')
```

to get the UTC start time with the proper day.

And the same again for the End Time.

Comment: Yeah - that would be the ideal solution but nothing seems to point to being able to access a local datetime. Everything is UTC or at the least the formula `utcNow()`

Comment: @markb I amended the answer with my ideas as to how that can be accomplished. ;-) You can find the documentation for those functions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#convertfromutc